# How to delete Wi-Fi password on shutdown?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, wireless-networking, security, passwords

I use a wireless network on my Windows 7 and 8. The problem is that I don't want to store the password I entered so I need to know if there is any method to delete saved passwords every time I shutdown the PC so no one can get the password anymore.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your question, but it  makes no sense to me. If you remove the password info completely from the system,it will not be password-protected. That seems to defeat the purpose of having a password in the first place.

Comment: @Xavierjazz I want to enter password every time I start windows. by default, windows saves the password I entered for a network and next time I start it, windows won't ask any password and this is my problem because other people in my office can access to the windows and they get the password. for some reasons, I can't forbid people using my account I just want them not to get the Wi-fi network password!

Comment: Windows will *only* save the password for the profile if *you* select that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the stored profile of every WLAN interface. By runnig following command.

```
netsh wlan delete profile name=[profile name] interface=[interface name]
```

This will delete, network from network list as well as password. But I think it will solve your problem.

You can save it as a fileName.bat and double click on system shut down, if you use same network every time, or you can do it automaticly on system shutdown open **gpedit.msc** to open the Group Policy Editor,
Navigate to Computer Configuration-> Windows Settings -> Scripts (Startup/Shutdow)

To delete all networks at one you could run this command.

```
netsh wlan delete profile name=*
```

Google out for more usage of netsh to adjust it to your need. I hope this will help.